# How to git copy a single folder to another project

Tags: git

I want to copy all the files and folders in a single folder, keeping the git history.

But not any files from other folders in the commits.

Answer (score 2):

I use this method frequently, all credit goes to http://st-on-it.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/how-to-move-folders-between-git.html

Make a copy of an existing repo or git clone into repocopy

Whatever you do, don't push!

```
cd repocopy

git checkout yourbranch

git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter yourfolder -- -- all

mkdir -p yourfolder

git status
```

Any files in .gitignore will remain so remove those normally

```
rm ignoredfiles
```

Then git mv (not mv) the remaining files and folders into yourfolder

```
git mv yourfiles yourfolder

git commit -m "yourfolder: copy of yourfolder in repocopy"
```

Now go to the main project

```
cd ../yourproject/

git remote add repo-repocopy ../repocopy

git fetch repo-repocopy

git branch feature_repocopy repo-repocopy/yourbranch

git checkout feature_yournewbranch

git merge --no-ff feature_repocopy
```